# Deploying Strapi in Vercel

Tags: deployment, strapi, vercel

I have a nextjs app deployed to Vercel, and am trying to deploy the Strapi cms that manages it to Vercel too, as it would be easier to maintain both on the same service.

The Strapi repo builds fine, and everything is green, but I either see a 404 if all settings are default, or a blank page if I set the build folder to be "build".

I'm sure it should be a simple fix, but I can't figure it out, has anyone done this?

Comment: I think the answer is somewhere in [vercel.json](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration). I haven't found yet, I'm still looking

Comment: I'm assuming this is something to do with Strapi not using default ports, but I've not confirmed yet.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's a way to deploy Strapi to Vercel.

Vercel is a frontend focused deploy service, while Strapi is a backend tool with a web interface.

Comment: this info missing on vercel homepage with big font - thx :-)

Answer (score 2):

As @gfpacheco says, you can't deploy Strapi CMS in Vercel, but you can do it in other platforms. I have personally used Heroku and their free tier. You can learn more this deployment option and others in  [Strapi's documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment.html)

Make sure to follow the official docs. Strapi is evolving fasts and tutorials quickly become obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can deploy the Strapi app and just make sure you have an access to your remote database somewhere else like an heroku or supabase db

Comment: Vercel does have Postgres now in their storage offer and Strapi supports Postgres as a database backend.

Answer (score -2):

Vercel is built to deploy mostly front end. I cam across this problem myself with Ghost CMS. They have a variety of CMS integrations that can be brought in, like Butter CMS and Contentful. However you can deploy Strapi to Digital Ocean and Heroku. I'm partial to heroku.

[Deploy a Next.js Blog Starter Using Strapi on Vercel](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-online-meetup-4-recap)